# Referencing graph nodes by integer ID

Tags: graph, chapel

As a bit of a learning project, I am working to replace a somewhat slow program in perl with a Chapel implementation.  I've got the algorithms down, but I'm struggling with the best way to reference the data in Chapel. I can do a direct translation, but it seems likely I'm missing a better way.

Details of existing program:

- I have a graph with ~32000 nodes and ~2.1M edges. State is saved in
  data files, but it's run as a daemon that keeps data in memory.
- Each node has a numeric ID (assigned by another system) and have a variety
  of other attributes defined by string, integer, and boolean values.
- The edges are directional and have a couple of boolean values
  attributed to them.
- I have an external system that interacts with this daemon that I cannot change. It makes requests, such as "Add node (int) with these attributes", "find shortest path from node (int) to node (int)", or "add edges from node (int) to node(s) (int, int, int)"

In Perl, the program uses hashes with common integer IDs for node and edge attributes. I can certainly replicate this in Chapel with associative arrays.

Is there a better way to bundle this all together?  I've been trying to wrap my head around ways to have opaque node and edge with each item defined, but struggling with how to reference them with the integer IDs in an easy fashion.

If somebody can provide an ideal way to do the following, it would get me the push I need.

- Create two nodes with xx attributes identified by integer ID.
- Create an edge between the two with xx attribues
- Respond to request "show me the xx attribute of node (int)"

Cheers, and thanks.

Comment: Do the edges have integer IDs assigned by another system as well? Or are the edges anonymous, in a way?

Comment: You mention that " I can certainly replicate this in Chapel with associative arrays". If the ideal way to accomplish this is with associative arrays, would it be correct to interpret this question as "How to create a graph with these features (bulleted at the end) as an associative array?"

Comment: @mppf - The edges are anonymous as well.

Comment: @bencray -  I'm new enough to Chapel to not know if there is a more appropriate/efficient method of storing the node/edge data and referencing them, so maybe a direct translation of my existing perl code is a poor choice.

Comment: I have been hit by this exact issue.  Ultimately I decided to take a GraphBLAS approach in my [Chingon](https://github.com/buddha314/chingon) project.  I wrapped a matrix in meta-data and allow vertex names using domains and arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you might expect, there are a number of ways to approach this in Chapel, though I think given your historical approach and your external system's interface, associative domains and arrays are definitely an appropriate way to go.  Specifically, given your desire to refer to nodes by integer IDs makes associative domains/arrays a natural match.

For Chapel newbies: associative domains are essentially sets of arbitrary values, like the set of integer node IDs in this case.  Associative arrays are mappings from the indices of an associative domain to elements (variables) of a given type .  Essentially, the domain represents the keys and the array the values in a key-value store or hash table.

To represent the nodes and edges themselves, I'm going to take the approach of using Chapel records.  Here's my record for a node:

```
record node {
  var id: int;

  var str: string,
      i: int,
      flag: bool;

  var edges: [1..0] edge;
}
```

As you can see, it stores its `id` as an integer, arbitrary attribute fields of various types (a string `str`, an integer `i`, and a boolean `flag` — you can probably come up with better names for your program), and an array of edges which I'll return to in a second.  Note that it may or may not be necessary for each node to store its ID... perhaps in any context where you'd have the node, you would already know its ID, in which case storing it could be redundant.  Here I stored it just to show you could, not because you must.

Returning to the edges:  In your question, it sounded as though edges might have their own integer IDs and get stored in the same pool as the nodes, but here I've taken a different approach:  In my experience, given a node, I typically want the set of edges leading out of it, so I have each node store an array of its outgoing edges.  Here, I'm using a dense 1D array of edges which is initially empty (`1..0` is an empty range in Chapel since `1 > 0`).  You could also use an associative array of edges if you wanted to give them each a unique ID.  Or you could remove the edges from the node data structure altogether and store them globally.  Feel free to ask follow-up questions if you'd prefer a different approach.

Here's my record for representing an edge:

```
record edge {
  var from, to: int,
      flag1, flag2: bool;
}
```

The first two fields (`from` and `to`) indicate the nodes that the edge connects.  As with the node ID above, it may be that the `from` field is redundant / unnecessary, but I've included it here for completeness.  The two flag fields are intended to represent the data attributes you'd associate with an edge.

Next, I'll create my associative domain and array to represent the set of node IDs and the nodes themselves:

```
var NodeIDs: domain(int),
    Nodes: [NodeIDs] node;
```

Here, `NodeIDs` is an associative domain (set) of integer IDs representing the nodes.  `Nodes` is a an associative array that maps from those integers to values of type `node` (the record we defined above).

Now, turning to your three operations:

> Create two nodes with xx attributes identified by integer ID.

The following declaration creates a node variable named `n1` with some arbitrary attributes using the default record constructor/initializer that Chapel provides for records that don't define their own:

```
var n1 = new node(id=1, "node 1", 42, flag=true);
```

I can then insert it into the array of nodes as follows:

```
Nodes[n1.id] = n1;
```

This assignment effectively adds `n1.id` to the `NodeIDs` domain and copies `n1` into the corresponding array element in `Nodes`.  Here's an assignment that creates a second anonymous node and adds it to the set:

```
Nodes[2] = new node(id=2, "node 2", i=133);
```

Note that in the code above, I've assumed that you want to choose the IDs for each node explicitly (e.g., perhaps your data file establishes the node IDs?).  Another approach (not shown here) might be to have them be automatically determined as the nodes are created using a global counter (maybe an atomic counter if you're creating them in parallel).

Having populated our Nodes, we can then iterate over them serially or in parallel (here I'm doing it in parallel; replacing `forall` with `for` will make them serial):

```
writeln("Printing all node IDs (in an arbitrary order):");
forall nid in NodeIDs do
  writeln("I have a node with ID ", nid);

writeln("Printing all nodes (in an arbitrary order):");
forall n in Nodes do
  writeln(n);
```

The order in which these loops print the IDs and nodes is arbitrary for two reasons:  (1) they're parallel loops; (2) associative domains and arrays store their elements in an arbitrary order.

> Create an edge between the two with xx attribues

Since I associated the edges with nodes, I took the approach of creating a method on the `node` type that will add an edge to it:

```
proc node.addEdge(to: int, flag1: bool, flag2: bool) {
  edges.push_back(new edge(id, to, flag1, flag2));
}
```

This procedure takes the destination node ID, and the attributes as its arguments, creates an edge using that information (and supplying the originating node's ID as the `from` field), and uses the `push_back()` method on rectangular arrays to add it to the list of edges.

I then call this routine three times to create some edges for node 2 (including redundant and self-edges since I only have two nodes so far):

```
Nodes[2].addEdge(n1.id, true, false);
Nodes[2].addEdge(n1.id, false, true);
Nodes[2].addEdge(2, false, false);
```

And at this point, I can loop over all of the edges for a given node as follows:

```
writeln("Printing all edges for node 2: (in an arbitrary order):");
forall e in Nodes[2].edges do
  writeln(e);
```

Here, the arbitrary printing order is only due to the use of the parallel loop.  If I'd used a serial `for` loop, I'd traverse the edges in the order they were added due to the use of a 1D array to represent them.

> Respond to request "show me the xx attribute of node (int)"

You've probably got this by now, but I can get at arbitrary attributes of a node simply by indexing into the `Nodes` array.  For example, the expression:

```
...Nodes[2].str...
```

would give me the string attribute of node 2.  Here's a little helper routine I wrote to get at (and print) some various attributes):

```
proc showAttributes(id: int) {
  if (!NodeIDs.member(id)) {
    writeln("No such node ID: ", id);
    return;
  }

  writeln("Printing the complete attributes for node ", id);
  writeln(Nodes[id]);

  writeln("Printing its string field only:");
  writeln(Nodes[id].str);
}
```

And here are some calls to it:

```
showAttributes(n1.id);
showAttributes(2);
showAttributes(3);
```

> I am working to replace a somewhat slow program in perl with a Chapel implementation

Given that speed is one of your reasons for looking at Chapel, once your program is correct, re-compile it with the `--fast` flag to get it running quickly.

Comment: For reference, here's a link to the Chapel primer on associative domains and arrays:  http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/primers/associative.html

Comment: **Talking about the code-execution performance** *( and yet bearing in mind a random ordering and by definition an open ended story with an a priori uncertain graph topology )* what means does Chapel syntax provide so as to indicate a designer's  intent to align records / data along the cache-line boundaries? Is there any explicit syntax for requesting a cache-friendly layout, or does this sort of design-align specific efforts fully belong just to the compiler / linker process, that helps the layouts to become best cache-friendly aligned per platform?

Comment: At present, Chapel doesn't have any way of specifying/controlling field layout/padding within records.  In practice, I believe the compiler passes the equivalent struct to the back-end (C or LLVM) compiler and lets it do what  it wants with it.

Comment: If you are working consistently with graphs, you may wish to follow [this ticket](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/6840) .  I'm hoping to find a good Chapel-compatible graph system. Something like igraph but distributed

Comment: How would you ask "show me all nodes with `str=='brad'`

Comment: Using the representation above, it'd be:

forall n in Nodes do 
  if n.str == 'brad' then
    writeln(n);

If you wanted to do this in less than O(Nodes) time, you'd want to build an associative array mapping strings to node numbers.